# Mysql query for winners in the contest including draws entries having score in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running contests on my website. Every contest could have multiple entries. I want to retrieve the best 3 entries or more (in the case of draw) based on the score. The score is calculated as the sum of the score of all votes.

Here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2480

The table ENTRY is as follows:

```
id    contest_id
1     1          
2     1          
3     1          
4     1          
5     1          
6     1          
7     1          
8     1          
9     1
```

The table ENTRY_VOTE is as follow:

```
id    entry_id    score
-- entry 1 has 20 votes (5+10+5)
1     1           5
2     1           10
3     1           5
-- entry 2 has 20 votes (10+10)
4     2           10
5     2           10
-- entry 3 has 25 votes (5+5+5+10)
6     3           5
7     3           5
8     3           5
9     3           10
-- entry 4 has 10 votes (10)
10    4           10
-- entry 5 has 25 votes (10+10+5)
11    5           10
12    5           10
13    5           5
-- entry 6 has 5 votes (5)
14    6           5
-- entry 7 has 50 votes (10+10+10+10+10)
15    7           10
16    7           10
17    7           10
18    7           10
19    7           10
-- entry 8 has 20 votes (10+10)
20    8           10
21    8           10
-- entry 9 has 5 votes (5)
22    9           5
```

The result should be (with draws):

```
id (entry_id) contest_id  score
7             1           50
3             1           25
5             1           25
1             1           20
2             1           20
8             1           20
```

I'm trying the follow query:

```
select * from (
     select entry.*, sum(score) as final_score from entry join entry_vote on 
     entry.entry_id = entry_vote.entry_id group by entry_id
) as entries
where final_score in (
    select distinct(final_score) from (
        select entry_id, sum(score) as final_score from entry_vote group by entry_id
    ) as final_scores order by final_score desc limit 3;
)
```

The first subquery returns all entries with all entry_vote score summed.
The second subquery returns the top 3 distincts summed scores (50, 25 and 20).
This query is returning error. What is wrong and how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2480/50/0

I managed to solve the query by using joins instead of subquery.
The query i posted on the question are getting error because the second subquery was finishing with ";":

```
select distinct(final_score) from (
    select entry_id, sum(score) as final_score from entry_vote group by entry_id
) as final_scores order by final_score desc limit 3;
```

Solving this, the next error will be the limit inside subqueries. Mysql does not support them.

The final query is:

```
select * from (
    select entry.*, sum(score) as score from entry 
    join entry_vote on entry.entry_id = entry_vote.entry_id where entry.contest_id = <CONTEST_ID> group by entry_id
) as entry_with_score join (
    select distinct(score) as score from (
        select sum(score) as score from entry_vote 
        join entry on entry_vote.entry_id = entry.id 
        join contest on audition.contest_id = contest.id where contest.id = <CONTEST_ID> group by entry_id
    ) as score_by_entry order by score desc limit 3
) as top_score on entry_with_score.score = top_score.score;
```

Comment: I forgot to add where clause with contest id. Will update the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following code

```
SELECT entry_id, SUM(score) AS score FROM entry_vote GROUP BY entry_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: I want the entries with the top 3 scores

Comment: i have edited the SQL ,it will provides you the top 3 scores.

Comment: No, you don't understand the question. This query is wrong because limiting with 3 will bring only 50 and 25, but the correct are the entries with score 50, 25, and 20

Comment: Your script is not working because - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: For second result,which one you want to get  1 =20,2 =20,8 =20 just tell me i can write a store procedure.

Comment: OK i managed to work with join. My query was wrong because the subquery was finishing with ";", solving this the error was because Mysql does not support LIMIT in subqueries. I will answer my own question =(

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT entry_id,total
   FROM 
      ( SELECT x.*
             , IF(@prev=total,@i,@i:=@i+1) i,@prev:=total prev 
          FROM 
             ( SELECT entry_id
                    , SUM(score) total
                 FROM entry_vote
                GROUP 
                   BY entry_id
             ) x
             , (SELECT @i:=0,@prev:=NULL)vars 
         ORDER 
            BY total DESC
      ) a
  WHERE i <=3;
```